# Parsing email with Email::MIME and multipart/mixed with subparts

Tags: perl, email, mime-types

I'm a perl novice and have been working with Email::MIME to figure out how to parse emails with multiparts correctly. I've just identified another combination that my current efforts have not been able to properly read.

```
     Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="===============1811908679642194059=="
 MIME-Version: 1.0

 This is an OpenPGP/MIME signed message (RFC 4880 and 3156)
 --===============1811908679642194059==
 Content-Type: multipart/signed; micalg=pgp-sha256;
  protocol="application/pgp-signature";
  boundary="lGJM242FL2E9Wh4auTNwQRWOeFI0Wj9mB"

 This is an OpenPGP/MIME signed message (RFC 4880 and 3156)
 --lGJM242FL2E9Wh4auTNwQRWOeFI0Wj9mB
 Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
  boundary="------------CC2F0C038668F58F6EDEA0D2"

 This is a multi-part message in MIME format.
 --------------CC2F0C038668F58F6EDEA0D2
 Content-Type: text/plain; charset=windows-1252
 Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

 =3D=3D=3D=3D=3D=3D=3D=3D=3D=3D=3D=3D=3D=3D=3D=3D=3D=3D=3D=3D=3D=3D=3D=3D=3D=
 =3D=3D=3D=3D=3D=3D=3D=3D=3D=3D=3D=3D=3D=3D=3D=3D=3D=3D=3D=3D=3D=3D=3D=3D=3D=
 =3D=3D=3D=3D=3D=3D=3D=3D=3D=3D=3D=3D=3D=3D=3D=3D=3D=3D=3D=3D=3D=3D=3D=3D
```

The text/plain part is the part that I want, but reading the "text" component just gives me the "This is a multi-part..." line and that's it. This is the code I've developed to read other emails with similar subparts, but it doesn't properly interpret this one.

It looks to be related to the "body" function as part of Email::MIME:

```
 This decodes and returns the body of the object as a byte string. For
 top-level objects in multi-part messages, this is highly likely to be
 something like "This is a multi-part message in MIME format."
```

What is the proper function to use within Email::MIME to properly read this content type?

How do properly identify the content-type in this email? Is it "multipart/mixed" or "text/plain" or "multipart/alternative"?

Do I even want to use the subparts method here?

```
 my @mailData;
 my $msg = Email::MIME->new($buf);
 foreach my $part ( $msg->subparts ) {
    foreach my $sub_part ($part->subparts) {
         print $sub_part->content_type;
        if ($sub_part->content_type =~ m!text!) {
            @mailData = split( '\n', $sub_part->body);
         }
    }
 }
```

The code above only prints "This is a multi-part message..." in the @mailData array.

Comment: Added code, oops. Thanks.

Comment: Since no one has given this a try, I'll give it a go.  It looks like you are only looking in the second level of "parts" for your text message.   Maybe use the walk_parts method to go through all of the email's parts?  You could just print out the type and body of each one to see where your content may be.  Hopefully give you more of clue of what is happening in your email.

Comment: What I've learned is that my code only displays (can only access) one of the text/ascii parts, while using walk_parts is able to access all the parts. I'm still not entirely sure this would be the proper way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've spent the last few days working with Email::MIME, MIME::Parser and MIME::Entity in order to automate the processing of a number of emails. I've found there are so few standard ways of encoding the same email, that it was much more difficult than I thought.

This is a pretty reliable way to process both the headers and body of an email. Thanks so much for all who helped along the way.

```
 #!/usr/bin/perl -w

 use strict;
 use MIME::Parser;
 use MIME::Entity;
 use Email::MIME;

 # Read the email from STDIN
 my $buf;
 while(<STDIN> ){
         $buf .= $_;
 }

 # This creates msg-NNNN-N.txt and signature-N.asc files
 # and I don't know why. Related to output_to_core?
 my $parser = MIME::Parser->new;
 $parser->extract_uuencode(1);
 $parser->extract_nested_messages(1);
 $parser->output_to_core(0);

 # For reading headers
 my $entity = $parser->parse_data($buf);

 # For reading the body (of an mbox)
 my $msg = Email::MIME->new($buf);

 # Use MIME::Entity to read various headers. 
 my $subject = $entity->head->get('Subject');
 my $from = $entity->head->get('From');
 my $AdvDate = $entity->head->get('Date');
 $AdvDate =~ s/\n//g; $subject =~ s/\n//g; $from =~ s/\n//g;

 print "Subject: $subject\n";
 print "From: $from\n";
 print "Date: $AdvDate\n";

 my @mailData;

  # walk through all the different attachments. Stop at the first one that matches and
  # read its contents into mailData. The first one typically appeared to be the primary one.
  $msg->walk_parts(sub {
      my ($part) = @_;
      #warn($part->content_type . ": " . $part->subparts);
      if (($part->content_type =~ /text\/plain; charset=\"?utf-8\"?/i) && !@mailData) {
         #print $part->body;
         @mailData = split( '\n', $part->body);
      }
      elsif (($part->content_type =~ /text\/plain; charset=\"?us-ascii\"?/i) && !@mailData) {
         #print $part->body;
         @mailData = split( '\n', $part->body);
      }
      elsif (($part->content_type =~ /text\/plain; charset=\"?windows-1252\"?/i) && !@mailData) {
         #print $part->body;
         @mailData = split( '\n', $part->body);
      }
      elsif (($part->content_type =~ /text\/plain; charset=\"?iso-8859-1\"?/i) && !@mailData) {
         #print $part->body;
         @mailData = split( '\n', $part->body);
      }
  });


 # manipulate the body of the message stored in mailData
 foreach my $line (@mailData) {
        print "$line\n";
 }
```